# Is this image, taken about 1900, actually from Nuremberg?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth, history, landmarks, zurich

I'm trying to identify the place (and if possible the building, the church and the fountain) in this image:

[image: A street in Nuremberg]

The image is labelled as a street in Nuremberg and taken between 1880 and 1912. However, I haven't been able to match the two church towers in the background to any church in Nuremberg. From other images in the collection, we can confirm [that the photographer was in Nuremberg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Carrer_de_Nuremberg_(AFCEC_VIDAL_A_0589)_Restored.jpg) and other Bavarian cities, but some images weren't properly labelled (for example, an [image originally labelled as being Pappenheim](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vista_de_la_Marienplatz_de_Munic.jpg) actually showed Munich's Marienplatz).

Then, the image could actually be Nuremberg or if it isn't Nuremberg it's likely to be another Bavarian city.

The image can be also found at https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Un_carrer_de_Nuremberg.jpeg or in its original location at http://mdc.csuc.cat/cdm/singleitem/collection/afceccf/id/22180/rec/936

A summary of my motives to ask about location of old photographs is in [my previous question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158244/where-is-this-tower-likely-photographed-in-belgium-about-100-years-ago).

Comment: Someone posted a very similar Photo on reddit just a few days ago, together with a current one taken from the same location: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/Switzerland/comments/hh196h/limmatquai_in_zurich_in_the_1890s_compared_to_a/

Comment: @rmweiss - And judging by the railing, that image in Reddit seems to be even older than this one.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The church would appear to be the [Grossmünster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grossm%C3%BCnster) in Zürich.

[image]
<sup>[New In Zürich](https://newinzurich.com/grossmunster/)</sup>

The towers are quite distinctive, and the tip of the spire at the rear of the church (seen here between the towers) is just visible in your photo to the left of the left tower.

The building in the foreground of your photo - the [Haus zum Rüden*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haus_zum_R%C3%BCden) - appears to the left in this image, and has a new roof.

The building to the right of your photo also appears in this image, next to the bridge.

There are what appear to be power lines suspended above the street, and tramlines set in the roadway. This would date the photograph to no earlier than 1894 when the first electric tramway opened in Zürich (source:[Trams in Zürich](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trams_in_Z%C3%BCrich)).

Here is a screenshot from Google Maps:

[image: Grossmünster church in Zurich on google maps]

<sup>* Thanks to @tuhuwawohu for the name of this building</sup>

Comment: In facts it's Zurich. The building in the center of the old pic is the "Haus zum Rüden" - Google Streetview: https://goo.gl/maps/6hAQnaNjbdLHu7b68 - and a historical pic from 1898: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Haus_R%C3%BCden_1898.jpg (i was a little bit too slow to answer it myself ;-) )

Comment: Great job. Interestingly, the guarding whose shadow can be seen in the photograph is still the same.

Comment: Here is a [Google map view](https://goo.gl/maps/Rp4pTrmiuaYKW37V7) with the fountain.

Comment: Can we also get an approximate year for the photo? The tram has been electrified and the inscription on the building seems rather worn off.

Comment: @asdfex Earliest date added. Thanks for the hint

Comment: In the Wikimedia image from 1898 there's still a horse drawn carriage on this route. I'm not familiar with the exact dates of electrification.

Comment: @asdfex I linked to my source for the date of electrification. The presence of electric trams doesn't preclude horse drawn trams. Some routes may not have been completely electrified but use the same  track for part of the route.

Comment: @asdfex, Arthur: actually the tram line in the picture is already electrified, and the carriage is just a plain old carriage that happens to be near the tram rails, but is not connected to them. Actual horse-drawn trams looked quite different. But nice to see that the tram is still there today :)

Comment: @rob74 I know, I referred to the image in Wikipedia, dated 1898, which means that this image here was made later.  https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Haus_R%C3%BCden_1898.jpg

Comment: I know this street and the cables seem wrong for a tram. Maybe they are just connecting houses or street lamps to the grid.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest asking the [Nuremberg Municipal Museums](https://museums.nuernberg.de/nuremberg-municipal-museums/) about this image or others tagged as Nürnberg.

Local museums are often interested in receiving such images taken by visitors since sometimes angles, viewpoints or a timeframe may complement their existing collections.

Based on @Arthur'sPass answer, which looks to me like a realistic candidate, the details on the right of your image might be of interest to a local museum in Zürich.

---

Nuremberg Municipal Museums
Direction and Administration
Hirschelgasse 9-11
90403 Nuremberg
Tel. +49 (0)911 231 - 54 21
Fax +49 (0)911 231 - 54 22

Florian Dierl M.A.
Department Head, Culture of Remembrance

**dokumentationszentrum@stadt.nuernberg.de**

---

**Sources**:

- [Nuremberg Municipal Museums](https://museums.nuernberg.de/nuremberg-municipal-museums/)

Comment: As far as I can see, the other images tagged as Nuremberg are more clearly from Nuremberg. That's why I didn't include any other image in the question. Furthermore, I'm amazed of how fast I'm getting good answers here. It seems that crowd-sourcing expertise is more efficient than asking to museums - especially with those images, where I had asked the wrong museum.

Comment: About informing Nuremberg Museum about this particular image, it would be better to point them to https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Nuremberg_by_century which contains several hundreds of historical images - including this one. However, I expect them to already know about that unless they have an even better tool to find the same images.