# Where is this chained man statue, photographed a century ago?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth, belgium, brussels, history

According to metadata, this image is claimed to be taken between 1880 and 1926 and the location is stated just as "Europe".

If the photographer is correctly identified, most of [his photographs](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Photographs_by_Joaquim_Morell%C3%B3_i_Nart) were taken in Catalonia and Spain and a few of them near the Alps.

I haven't been able to find the statue anywhere, neither with reverse image search nor by searching for sculpture groups with a chained man.

[image]

The image and metadata comes from [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Monument_en_un_parc.jpeg) in Wikimedia Commons and it can also be found in [its original location](https://mdc.csuc.cat/digital/collection/afceccf/id/18848).

I'd like to identify the image in order to properly label it in Wikimedia Commons. Some background information is in [a previous question about another image](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158244/where-is-this-tower-likely-photographed-in-belgium-about-100-years-ago).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is the Sculpture "*Nègres marrons surpris par des chiens*" by Louis Samain. In the context of Slavery, the term "[marron](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marronnage_(esclavage))"<sup>French Wikipedia</sup> refers to fugitive slaves (cf. the english "[Maroons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maroons)"<sup>English Wikipedia</sup> for descendants of enslaved Africans in the Americas who escaped and formed free settlements). The sculpture dates from 1895; nowadays, there's [an public controversion about it in Belgium](https://www.rtbf.be/info/regions/detail_negres-marrons-surpris-par-des-chiens-une-uvre-jugee-raciste-au-bout-de-l-avenue-louise?id=10527309).

The is sculpture located between Avenue Louise 505 and Avenue Louise 510, Bruxelles, Belgium, near the Tram Station Legrand. Here's a modern pic from Wikimedia Commons (which even has an [own category dedicated to this sculpture](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:N%C3%A8gres_marrons_surpris_par_des_chiens)):

[image]
<sup>Karmakolle, [CC BY-SA 4.0](http://://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wikibruz23.jpg)</sup>

Google has no streetview from the very spot, but the sculpture [is visible on this pic](https://goo.gl/maps/4WEyx814wDRFfBEy8):

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118010/discussion-on-answer-by-tohuwawohu-where-is-this-chained-man-statue-photographe). In this case the conversation has been moved because it is not related to the question. You are welcome to continue that conversation in the chatroom and to use the comments here about the actual answer. All comments to do with the French name of the statue and its meanings here will be deleted.